# ArcGIS Pro recieving error 000405: No records within table when records do in fact exist?

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I selected a subset (blue) of points from the feature class (red) which all have populated fields in the attribute table, and can be manually edited (by clicking each individually and typing a value) but cannot be batch edited by calculating field. When counted using tool, zero records are recognized and geoprocessing error `000405: no records within a table` is displayed.

Is anyone else having this problem in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Pro are you using?

Comment: What format is the source data? It needs to be a spatial dataset so not gml or a web service.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro version 2.2.2, source data is a file geodatabase feature class